# PHP - PayPal Adaptive Payments (Delayed Chained Payments)

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-adaptive-payments

I really need your help guys. Am currently developing my marketplace website but the web developers am using is not really good with PayPal.

To make sure everyone on the is comfortable about using the site I have decided to use PayPal Adaptive Payment - Delayed Chained Payments.

There are two ways to pay for a job on the site.
1) Giving someone a job directly.

In this option, what we want is that when the person who is giving the job to someone on the site has completed the job details, when it gets to payment page he/she will pay through PayPal (it will look like he/she is still within the site) but he/she will also be aware that the funds will not be made available to the site and the person doing the job until he has log back into his /her paypal account and click on a checkbox or button that says "Job Completed".

2) Allowing job seekers to bid for the job.
In this option, when the person indicate that he/she wants people to bid for the job, we want that on the job form, when the person clicks on any job service fee offer, he/she will be taken to paypal (it will look like he/she is still within the site), where he/she will make the payment. But he/she will also be aware that the funds will not be made available to the site and person doing the job until he has log back into his /her paypal account and click on a checkbox or button that says "Job Completed".

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks
Ben.

Comment: So what's your question exactly?

Comment: How do I use PayPal Adaptive Payment to do (1) and (2) below;

Comment: How do I use PayPal Adaptive Payment to do (1) and (2) in the original question.

Comment: Do you have an email, so I can email you the description in more detail?

Answer (score 1):

I've got a [PHP class library for PayPal](http://www.angelleye.com/overview-of-php-class-library-for-paypal/) that would make this very simple for you.  I'm an official PayPal Partner, a Certified PayPal Developer, a PayPal Ambassador, and a 3-time PayPal Star Developer Award winner, so you can rest assured it'll work nicely for you.

I generally offer 30 min of free training, too, which is usually more than enough to get people up-and-running as long as you understand PHP and how to work with array data.

Answer (score 0):

you can integrate same as like:
https://github.com/paypal/adaptivepayments-sdk-php

for adaptive payment paypal .

Thanks
JAY